# Google Doc with "Document Tab"?

Tags: google-docs

I had a google doc shared with me where the owner had added tabs. Super cool. I cannot find anywhere to add this to existing documents. It essentially makes a Google Doc into a tabbed document. Kind of like a OneNote document. I find myself in a backwater of unsearchable generic terms.

The Doc looks like the attached image. Any idea to enable this for existing documents? Or documentation on it?

[image: Google Doc Document Tab]

Comment: Are there any extensions enabled?

Comment: No.   I wondered the same.   Also no Scripts attached.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the feature is **Document Outline**. Old and new docs show a button on the left side below the Google Docs log > Zoom (magnifier icon). On hover it shows **Show document outline**.

**Button**
[image: Show document outline button showing the Show document outline title]

**Button context**
[image: New Google Docs document in pageless mode]

---

---

Google Docs has a feature to help to find options in menus

1. Open the document
2. Click the **Help** menu, then **Search the menus**
3. In the search box, type **outline**

[image: Google Docs Help search dialog with outline word written in the search box].

Alternative

Option 1:

1. Open the document
2. Click the **Help** menu, then **Help**
3. In the search box type **outline**. The autocomplete feature will show several options

[image: Google Docs Help > Help search dialog with outline word written in the search box]
4. Click on one of the options or try a different *search query*.

Option 2:

1. Go to https://support.google.com/docs
2. In the search box type **outline** and press **enter**
3. Look at the search results and/or try a different *search query*.